# Sequlize How to make bulkCreate with associated table and not create new values if theay already exist in table

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express, sequelize.js

I Have 2 models. Actors And Movies, they have BelongsToMany Asscociation

```
  const Movie = sequelize.define(
  MOVIES,
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    year: {
      type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    format: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: [VHS, DVD, BLU_RAY],
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    indexes: [
      {
        unique: true,
        fields: ['title'],
      },
    ],
  }
);


const Actor = sequelize.define(
  ACTORS,
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    indexes: [
      {
        unique: true,
        fields: ['name'],
      },
    ],
  }
);
```

and this logic:

```
   const moviesData = req.files.movies.data.toString();

      const newMovies = movieHelper.formatArrayOfMovieObjects(moviesData);

      const movies = await Movie.bulkCreate(newMovies, {
        include: {
          model: Actor,
        },
        updateOnDuplicate: ['title'],
      });

      res.json(movies).status(200);
```

How to make to not create new records if movie.title exist in table

I tried updateOnDuplicate param but it give me this error: **[Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your SQLite version supports unique constraints/indexes then you can create one indicating the `title` field and this way the option `updateOnDuplicate` should work well.

Comment: I already created, u can see this on models indexes: [
      {
        unique: true,
        fields: ['title'],
      },

It's not work

Comment: Did you check the constraint/index in the DB?

Comment: Yes, in db i see this indexes

Comment: i Added screen with error. Seems is proplem in assosiated table actors_movies, it try to insert -24 id value and that i got error i think

Comment: Please add the content of `moviesData`